# Delay Initialization of One jQuery Plugin Until Another Has Finished

Tags: jquery, responsive-design, flexslider

I'm using [Response JS](http://responsejs.com/) and [Flexslider](http://www.woothemes.com/flexslider/) on a - you guessed it - responsive project. The site's slideshow pager will be in 2 different places depending on the size of the viewport, and I'm using Response JS to populate that code. The problem, though, is that Flexslider initializes before Response JS populates the pager code, so Flexslider can't find the pager its supposed to use.

Is there a way to initialize the Flexslider plugin only after Response JS has finished doing its magic on the page?

My markup goes something like this:

```
<body data-responsejs='{
    "create": [
    { "breakpoints": [0,320,481,641,961], "mode": "markup", "prefix": "r" }
    ]}'
>
    <div data-r961="
        <ul class=&quot;flexslider-pager&quot;>
            <li><img src=&quot;whatever.jpg&quot; alt=&quot;whatever&quot;></li>
            <li><img src=&quot;whatever.jpg&quot; alt=&quot;whatever&quot;></li>
            <li><img src=&quot;whatever.jpg&quot; alt=&quot;whatever&quot;></li>
        </ul>
    "></div>

    <div class="flexslider"><!-- Slideshow Here --></div>

    <div data-r481="
        <ul class=&quot;flexslider-pager&quot;>
            <li><img src=&quot;whatever.jpg&quot; alt=&quot;whatever&quot;></li>
            <li><img src=&quot;whatever.jpg&quot; alt=&quot;whatever&quot;></li>
            <li><img src=&quot;whatever.jpg&quot; alt=&quot;whatever&quot;></li>
        </ul>
    "></div>

    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="response.js"></script>
    <script src="flexslider.js"></script>
    <script>
        $('.flexslider').flexslider({
            manualControls: '.flexslider-pager li',
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

I've tried adding jQuery and Response JS to the head of the page, but with no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I came up with what is undoubtedly an extremely ugly solution:

```
function runPlugins(){
    $('.flexslider').flexslider();
};

Response.create({ 
    mode: 'markup', 
    prefix: 'r', 
    breakpoints: [0,600,820,901] 
}); 

jQuery(runPlugins);
```

I took the Response JS data attributes out of the body tag, and used the Response.create method instead. Then someone suggested I make the plugin calls a function, then call the function after creating the Response data attributes. I have no idea why it works, but it does.